# My Dropdownbutton items is not showing by apply a check in flutter using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have 2 dropdowns, on selecting a value in 1st dropdown the other will load items on the selection of the 1st dropdown.
But when I apply condition on the (listofItems) of the second dropdown to show only specific items which are assign to the item of the 1st dropdown then my 2nd dropdown will not clickable and then I press (ctrl + S) on my code in VS, then the dropdown is clickable.

I think there is a state update issue but I found nothing.

Comment: Did you wrap your dropwdown with Obx or Getbuilder? Also can you show us the code how far you are now?

Comment: please provide sample code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.